# RxJS Observable with initial value

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular-2+

Is it possible to get rid of the BehaviourSubject to have an Observable with an initial value? Another thing I don't like is that I'm using getValue() and then modify this value and push it with next back to the Observable. Maybe there is a more elegant way to get the same thing?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class UserProvider {

  users$: Observable<{ id: string; name: string }[]>;

  private usersSource: BehaviorSubject<{ id: string; name: string }[]>;

  constructor() {
   this.usersSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([
     { id: '111', name: 'Jack' },
     { id: '222', name: 'John' },
     { id: '333', name: 'Foo' },
   ]);
   this.users$ = this.usersSource.asObservable();
  }

  addUser(user: { id: string; name: string }) {
    const currentUsers = this.usersSource.getValue();
    currentUsers.push(user);
    this.usersSource.next(currentUsers);
  }

  removeUser(userId: string) {
    const currentUsers = this.usersSource.getValue();
    const index = currentUsers.findIndex(user => user.id === userId);
    if (index !== -1) {
      if (this.selectedUserIdSource.getValue() === currentUsers[index].id) {
        this.selectedUserIdSource.next(null);
      }
      currentUsers.splice(index, 1);
      this.usersSource.next(currentUsers);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: uset `Subject` instead which do not require initial value

Answer (score 5):

This is a really good question -- starred it! I am not very experienced with RxJs, but I believe your code around `BehaviorSubject` and `Observable` is as concise as possible.

`BehaviourSubject` itself is "subscribable" (just like an `Observable`) but it's a really bad practice to expose it directly to the consumer, i.e. your separation of `users$` and `usersSource` is a right thing to do. Exposing `Observable` is okay because it's designed to be read-only.

`usersSource.getValue()` is inevitable in your code, unless you decide to keep the usersSource state as a local field, but IMO it does not do any good in this scenario. Having state to be stored as a part of the `BehaviorSubject` is handy.

---

There are minor style things that could be improved in the code, but that's unrelated to RxJs, so I'll not comment on that.

---

## Update 1

Just a few months ago I was not aware of `.startsWith()` which seems to be an answer to a part of your question:

```
const neverButStartsWithZero = Rx.Observable
                                .never()
                                .startWith(0);
// Emits 0
const subscription1 = neverButStartsWithZero
                        .subscribe(value => console.log('subscription1:', value));

const threeEventsWithExtraZero = Rx.Observable
                                .of(1, 2, 3)
                                .startWith(0);
// Emits 0, 1, 2, 3
const subscription2 = threeEventsWithExtraZero
                        .subscribe(value => console.log('subscription2:', value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post but you could also do a getter for your example

```
get users$() {
  return this.usersSource$.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This may be the start of an answer, but it's not much of a review yet. Please see our help page on [How to write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).